# round() not rounding?

Tags: r

I am trying to use `round()` to round a numeric vector to 2 decimal places so I have consistent decimal places between different plots. I've seen people answer that I should use `round()` to do so and this was my first instinct as well. However, `round()` isn't rounding to 2 decimal places. I've tried multiple other decimal places and `round()` will only round to 0 or 1 decimal.

I'm using R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
I've tried this in base R with a clean session and no packages.

```
num_vec <- c(0.00, 
         0.50, 
         1.00, 
         1.50, 
         2.00, 
         2.50, 
         3.00, 
         3.50, 
         4.00, 
         4.50)

[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

round() will only round to 1 decomal point?

```r
round(num_vec,  digits = 2)
# [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5

round(num_vec,  digits = 1)
# [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

here round() will round to 0 decimal

```r
round(num_vec,  digits = 0)
# [1] 0 0 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4
```

round will not round to any other number of decimal points?

```r
base::round(num_vec, digits = 2)
# [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5

round(num_vec,  digits = 3)
# [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5

round(num_vec,  digits = 4)
# [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5
```

I've been using R for a long while and never encountered this problem. It could be I am doing something dumb here as I'm very tired (working on thesis...). I don't know this doesn't seem like it should be an issue...

Comment: You are confusing rounding (a numeric operation) with formatting (a character operation).  If you want to display the number 1/2 as 0.50, you need to use a format that includes 2 d.p.  The number 0.50000000 is the same as 0.5 or 0.50, they are all already rounded to 2 decimal places.

Comment: My guess is the numbers are being stored with the rounded precision, but printed to the console with 1 decimal

Comment: To format to 2 d.p., you can use `sprintf("%.2f", num_vec)`.

Comment: @user2554330 Awsome Thanks!, just saw your comment. it works

Comment: Especially if you're using ggplot, use `scales::label_number(accuracy = 0.01)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [@user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554330/user2554330) is right. This has to do with how RStudio displays the values in the console.

For example:

```
num_vec <- c(0.00, 
             0.53333, 
             1.00, 
             1.50, 
             2.00, 
             2.50, 
             3.00, 
             3.50, 
             4.00, 
             4.50)

round(num_vec,  digits = 2)
```

Displays the following:

```
[1] 0.00 0.53 1.00 1.50 2.00 2.50 3.00 3.50 4.00 4.50
```

But because **your example vector had only zeroes to the first decimal that could be truncated**, R did not display the values.

As mentioned earlier, `sprintf("%.2f", num_vec)` works nicely.